# Dead Letter Drops

Tags: word, anagram, letters

Start with a word.
For each line below, drop the indicated number of letters from it, rearranging if necessary, to form a word with the (probably cryptical) meaning given.  The first line clues your starting word.
You will end up one answer word per line, with each successive word being successively shorter.

> |  |  |
> | --- | --- |
> | 0 | Started a growth spurt |
> | -1 | Moved to Canada, perhaps |
> | -2 | Won back |
> | -3 | Sojourn to warmer climes |
> | -4 | Unwilling guest? |
> | -5 | Designated |
> | -6 | Quality of wine and cheese quality |
> | -7 | Wordplay, for example |
> | -8 | Tolkien's universe |
> | -9 | A drop of golden sun |

When you have all the right words, you'll see you have all the right words.

Comment: Are whitespace characters counted in the "set of words' length"?

Comment: Each line corresponds to a single word, with the indicated crossword-esque clue.  Successive lines' words get successively shorter by one letter. There's no whitespace involved.

Comment: I strongly suspect there's another rule you haven't stated, namely that after removing a letter you can also change another letter. Is this true?

Comment: @astralfenix: Probably not, but note that the subtraction of letters is always from the original word, so that the word with six letters removed doesn't necessarily have all the letters of the one with seven letters removed. As I see it, the words at −8 and −9 may even be totally disjoint.

Comment: @MOehm Ah, that might explain it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Answer:

> - germinated
>  - emigrated
>  - regained
>  - migrate
>  - inmate
>  - named
>  - aged
>  - tag (credit to @Volatility: 'wordplay' is a possible tag on puzzling.stackexchange)
>  - ea
>  - d (2nd note on the c major scale after c)

Edit:

> @Oleslaw spotted that when -9 is 'd', the first letter of each word spells the original ('germinated').

Comment: -7 could be "tag" (as in [tag:wordplay]). I would say -9 is probably "d", and maybe the "word" rule isn't *completely* tight.

Comment: The Tolkien one could be ARDA and the last one RAY. There's no question that "Ea" is better than "Arda" but there's equally no question that "Ray" is better than "D" or "I" or any other single-letter option. (But your others are pretty convincing and require the last one to be just one letter.) Another single-letter option would be N (one letter of both "golden" and "sun") but like D it isn't a word.

Comment: if you make the -7 "tag", -8 "ea" and -9 "D" the first letters of each word spell the full word...

Comment: @oleslaw ah, and hence "When you have all the right words, you'll see you have all the right words."

Comment: Sounds pretty convincing. I remark that in the first clip of "The Sound of Music" I found on Youtube, they actually sing that song in B flat, so the note that's "a drop of golden sun" is a C, not a D.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan But the "re" (ray) in solmization is "D" note anyways.

Comment: @oleslaw Yes and no. There are two ways of doing it, "fixed do" where the correspondence between names and *pitches* is fixed, and "movable do"  where the correspondence between names and *scale degrees* is fixed. The "fixed do" system is used in Austria, where TSOM is set, and there indeed re=D. But the "movable do" system is used in the US, where the movie was made, and there re can be any note. In the actual movie, at least in the Youtube clip I found, they sing the song in B flat, and re=C.

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan All right - in my country we use only the "fixed do". Thanks for clearing this up.

Comment: Great job, great teamwork.  Hope that was fun for you!  (I know the note is a little iffy, but the other clues - in particular the *first letters = the word* - were designed to ensure it was unambiguous at the end.)